# Do Tantra Texts Or Hindu Texts Mention Eco-Friendly Kali/Durga Idols Visarjan

Tags: rituals, durga, kali, idols

Festival idols question : Hey guys, do Hinduism texts say anything about carrying out puja rituals in a way that is eco-friendly ?

Kinda alarming to see the visarjan of Kali/Durga Maa idols.

So much polyester nylon rayon saris as well as high-toxin acrylic toxic paints, chemicals & little plastic pieces going into rivers and oceans.

Fish, dolphins, whales, seals otters, they accidentally eat and choke on all that plastic stuff plus generates huge loads of micro-plastics which is very bad for earth.

This is killing the fish and pollution contamination of the water which animals live in and drink.

My understanding is when a lot of these texts were written, idols were more eco-friendly, made of clay, sand, stones, and such. So visarjan didn’t pollute or contaminate the water.

Is there anything in Hinduism texts about this for modern times of Kaliyug like possible solutions ?

Seems like there’s gotta be a more eco-friendly way to do this after Durga Puja & Kali Puja.

Or like maybe do it symbolically or something.

Cause isn’t polluting and contaminating the water making bad karma too ? I have been wondering about this.

Edit : This looks like a humble-brag virtue-signaling post I realize. But I’ve actually been concerned about this for awhile, from vegan-environmentalist viewpoint of trying not to mess up animals and environment while just going about life etc.

Comment: It is not mentioned in Hindu Texts, as when the texts were written, everything was eco-friendly. Plastic and poly carbons were not invented yet.

Comment: @Up-In-Air Yeah, thx, seems to be the case. The idols look amazing, I just freak out seeing all that plastic and toxic paint going into the rivers and ocean. Little animals living in and drinking all that messed-up water ! Not good. More eco-friendly type stuffs is better for everyone. Hopefully environmentalists will try change things but sometimes I wonder, if they even can. It’s Kaliyug so things might get much worse before they get better right ? But still, can try say something and improve wherever, if possible

Comment: Sometimes on the news reports they show whales that have died much too young and there’s tons of plastic pieces in their stomachs :(